# Camel file polling, processing newly available files with highest priority

Tags: apache-camel

I had the following behaviour:
Had one end point when it is watching the folder(say input folder) in which files are available.
I have a route which refer to the above end point and copy the files to other folder(say output folder).

The current Behaviour is suppose say if you have 200 files in the input folder, then first your end point reads all the 200 files and send it to the route.

So here my requirement is:
suppose by that time it copies 200 files, if there are any other files arrived and it has to be taken priority(may be based on certain parameter which I can define from my side) before 200 files copies.

how I can I set the priority for these newly arrived priority files??

Answer (score 0):

You need the `sortBy` option of the file endpoint:
`from("file://somefolder?sortBy=file:modified")`
For details visit the http://camel.apache.org/file2.html
"Sorting using sortBy" section.

Comment: yes it sorts the files but how ever it will not consider the files which are in priority when already files are scanned and taken for processing.           Ex: at starting End point already scanned and taken 50 files. and it(route) is processing and after priority files arrived. in this case the priority files will be processed after 50 files are completed processing.     So Basically here I would like to process the newly arrived priority files before 50 files are processed. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use another endpoint for high priority files or change the maxMessagesPerPoll(with eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false) to limit the messages to be polled. There's no sense in stopping the already started processing, and the additional folder checking operation will also reduce the performance.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. just would like to know one point: if we have 2 endpoints then what will be the execution priority of the end points? or both will run parallel. ?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. just would like to know few points: if we have 2 endpoints then what will be the execution priority of the end points? or both will run parallel. ?   and if we use eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false and limit the messages to poll then will there be any performance degrade ? and what abt memory consumption?

Comment: Yes in parallel. And having two endpoints will be much faster.

Comment: hi @cra6, if we have 2 end points, then do we need to have 2 routes? or can we manage with one route referring to both the end points? If possible can I have some sample code.

Comment: in continuation to my previous comment: For example my camel xml looks like: <endpoint <referring to the folder Z>  />  <route ref:<above end point> > $I have some code to do some opeartions$   </route> , so now in this case if I want to have another end point listening to the same folder as above end point how to manage with the same route.

Comment: hi Any idea on the above thing?